# Floating containers so that they are both at bottom

Tags: html, css

I have got a ul list which has several li elements which need to be floated left. 
Each li contains an image of variable height either 150px or 200px. So what we get is multiple boxes(li) with images inside them.
This is the exact html inside an li

```
<li class="photo">
<a href="#" class="photo-link">
        <img src="http://familytrees.genopro.com/MrSpock/pictures/200x150.jpg" class="photo-img">
        <span class="photo-title">MrSpock</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Now if an image in any of the li elements is of height 200px and the adjacent li has an image of height 150px, the li with image 150px height stacks up on the top right edge of the li with 200px height. ( Remember both are floated left)

I want the li elements to stack up as if they were boxes of diff height kept on a floor.

Restrictions : I cannot change this html, there can be multiple li elements in which case the images flow to the next row. We do not know in advance if all the images in a row will be of same or diff height.

Is there a CSS only solution possible for this ? Heres a link to my problem : 
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/88049315/home.html 
I want the containers in the first row to all align at the bottom.

Comment: Why can't you change the html?

Comment: what css have you tried?

Comment: Well honestly its part of a challenge I am doing which has the constraint that html cannot be changed. But even in the real world, I have heard scenarios where sites use a CMS and sometimes they get the html from somewhere and want you to style only using that html. 

@otherDewi : See the link provided to my attempt, the original challenge required me to align the containers in rows and all that which I did but cant get that container with MrSpock to be bottom aligned.

Comment: Guys, I did solve this eventually myself, however I apologise for passing on an assumption to everyone. The challenge was to style an unknown no of images so that they stack up on a page, and are bottom-aligned. 

The assumption I made was that float is the only way to go, which I kinda passed on when I asked my question saying containers are floated. The solution was to use display:inline-block, which has the same effect of stacking them and flowing to next lines but also bottom-aligns them so that even if they are of variable height, the shorter images still sit on the bottom of the row.

Answer (score 0):

What about this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SCnLW/)?

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

---

```
 #container
    {
        width:200px;
        height:200px;
        background-color:#333;
        display:table-cell;
        vertical-align:bottom
    }

    .content
    {
        width:48px;
        height:48px;
        background-color:red;
        float:left;
        margin: 1px;
    }
```

As long all the floating content together does not have a width larger then the container everything is fine. After that the float functionality takes over and positions the first line one row above the bottom.

Otherwise you could rotate the conainer div so all content in it goes with it. This is more of a hacky way and can cause issues further down the line. [The Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SCnLW/1/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer Menno. Here you have fixed the width of .content, in my case unfortunately this can vary - depending on if the image is of height 200px or 150px. But I still want the container's bottom edge aligned with all the other containers in the same row.